How to create migration and indexing for table created by airbyte automatically in Rails
I have a postgres database table which is created by airbyte automatically in rails app. I want to manage migration and indexing for new column. There is no mechanism right now to handle this since this table is automatically created by airbyte.
The following is the schema
CREATE TABLE public."KEYWORD_INSIGHTS" (
    t.bigint "ID"
    t.date "DATE"
    t.string "TERM"
    t.string "_airbyte_raw_id", limit: 36, null: false
    t.timestamptz "_airbyte_extracted_at", null: false
    t.jsonb "_airbyte_meta", null: false
    t.index ["_airbyte_extracted_at"], name: "KEYWORD_INSIGHTS_airbyte_tmp__airbyte_extracted_at_idx"
    t.index ["_airbyte_raw_id"], name: "KEYWORD_INSIGHTS_airbyte_tmp__airbyte_raw_id_idx"
)


if airbyte creates migration - modify migration, if not - create your own migration with changing anything
